# Grabbing data from an array using for loop to populate a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

**Problem**

I'm trying to iterate over an array of objects using a `for loop`, but instead of getting all the items in the array that I actually see when I `console.log(arr[i].Sand)` I get the same number eleven times in my HTML.

### script.js

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/fef35fba",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
    }).then(function(spreadsheet){

        // Array of objects
        var arr = spreadsheet.result;

        for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log(arr[i].Sand); // Just the volume of sand in tonnes

            var sand = arr[i].Sand // Volume of Sand in tonnes
            var salt = arr[i].Salt // Volume of Salt in tonnes
            var snow = arr[i].Snow // Snow Removal total in dollars

            // Changes the numbers in the table
            $(".sand").html(sand);
        }
    })
});
```

### spreadsheet.result

[image]

### index.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="year"></th>
            <th>
                <img src="img/sand-2.png" alt="" class="icons">
                <p>Volume of Sand</p>
                <p class="paren">(in tonnes)</p>
            </th>

            <th>
                <img src="img/salt-3.png" alt="" class="icons">
                <p>Volume of Salt</p>
                <p class="paren">(in tonnes)</p>
            </th>

            <th>
                <img src="img/snow-3.png" alt="" class="icons">
                <p>Snow Removal</p>
                <p class="paren">(total in dollars)</p>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="year">2016</th>
            <td class="sand">-<span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
            <td class="salt">-<span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
            <td class="snow">-<span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2015</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2014</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2013</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2012</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2011</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2010</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2009</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2008</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="year">2007</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="last">
            <td class="year">2006</th>
            <td class="sand">-</td>
            <td class="salt">-</td>
            <td class="snow">-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: show us a log of your spreadsheet.result

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Added image of spreadsheet.result

Comment: Well, the line you describe as "*Changes the numbers in the table*" doesn't really do that. It's sets the html contents of the set of elements in the jquery object, but that's just to make it more technically correct. So assuming it "changes the numbers in the table", do you see why you get the same value everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while I was generating the code to answer this, someone changed your ajax call.

Here's the code reworked so it should help.

```
    $(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/fef35fba",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
    }).then(function(spreadsheet){

        // Array of objects
        var arr = spreadsheet.result;

        for (i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log(arr[i].Sand); // Just the volume of sand in tonnes

             sand = arr[i].Sand // Volume of Sand in tonnes
             salt = arr[i].Salt // Volume of Salt in tonnes
             snow = arr[i].Snow // Snow Removal total in dollars
             year = arr[i].Year; //We need the year to find the right row

            // Changes the numbers in the table
            $("tr").each(function(){
                //We need to find the correct TR object.
     //Remove Any spacing outside the html to make sure we don't get anything extra. 
     // We need to locate the ROW that has the right year so we can populate ONLY it's columns. an id or class based off year would have made this easier and less resource expensive.

              if($(this).find(".year").html().trim() == year){ 

                $(this).find(".sand").html(sand);
                $(this).find(".salt").html(salt);
                $(this).find(".snow").html(snow);
              } 
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle to show it:
https://jsfiddle.net/g6vn4Lf6/

Comment: Works like a charm, can you elaborate on what's happening a bit more in your if statement, especially with the use of trim. Thanks!

Comment: Hope that helps, I've added a few notes. If you need more, let me know.

Comment: Lovely that explains a lot

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$(".sand").html(sand);
```

Finds *all* elements with `class="sand"` and then sets the inner html of all of them to the value of `sand`.  Instead you need to label each row of the table with html (eg `<tr class="year-2015">`), then you can select the right td element by using something like `$(".year-2015 .sand")`.

Comment: That does make sense, but is there a more efficient way? I'd like you to expand with a code sample.

Comment: There are more efficient ways, but it doesn't seem like you should be worrying about effieciency. You're biggest slowdown here is going to be the ajax request, its not going to be finding elements and setting their contents, which is nearly instantaneos either way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change the key of the year in your json response to `"year"` instead of `""`

Then you should associate that year with the tr's in some way, such as
`<tr year='2016'>`

Then in your for loop you can select just the .sand element that is a child of the correct tr.
`$("tr[year='" + arr[i].year + "'] .sand").html(sand)`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should dynamically add a row for each of the results you receive from your ajax call like shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrayResults = [
    { Year: '2016', Sand: '123', Salt: '234', Snow: '345' },
    { Year: '2015', Sand: '222', Salt: '333', Snow: '444' },
    { Year: '2014', Sand: '555', Salt: '111', Snow: '888' },
    { Year: '2013', Sand: '121', Salt: '232', Snow: '343' },
    { Year: '2012', Sand: '454', Salt: '565', Snow: '676' }
  ];

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayResults.length; i++) {
    var newRow = '<tr>';
    newRow += '<td class="year">' + arrayResults[i].Year + '</td>';
    newRow += '<td class="sand">' + arrayResults[i].Sand + '</td>';
    newRow += '<td class="salt">' + arrayResults[i].Salt + '</td>';
    newRow += '<td class="snow">' + arrayResults[i].Snow + '</td>';
    newRow += '</tr>';
    
    $('tbody').append(newRow);
  }
});
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>year</th><th>sand</th><th>salt</th><th>snow</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```